# List Name of employees whose names have 'i' is the second character

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb. I have below documents :

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "emp_id": 7369,
        "ename": "smith",
        "job": "analyst",
        "mgr": 7902,
        "hiredate": "17/12/1980",
        "salary": 800,
        "comm": null,
        "deptno": 20
    },
    {
        "_id": 5,
        "emp_id": 7654,
        "ename": "martin",
        "job": "salesman",
        "mgr": 7698,
        "hiredate": "28/09/1981",
        "salary": 1250,
        "comm": 1400,
        "deptno": 30
    },
    {
        "_id": 8,
        "emp_id": 7839,
        "ename": "king",
        "job": "president",
        "mgr": null,
        "hiredate": "17/11/1981",
        "salary": 5000,
        "comm": null,
        "deptno": 10
    },
    {
        "_id": 13,
        "emp_id": 7934,
        "ename": "miller",
        "job": "clerk",
        "mgr": 7782,
        "hiredate": "23/01/1982",
        "salary": 1300,
        "comm": null,
        "deptno": 10
    }
]
```

But I want to display the documents whose `enames` have '**i**' is the `second` character. I went through few sites but I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`$regex` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) that you can use to query the textual contents of your documents.

> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings
>   in queries. MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e.
>   “PCRE” ) version 8.36 with UTF-8 support.

For your case, the query would look something like this:

```
db.col.find({ ename: { $regex: /^.i/ } });
```

- `^` indicates the beginning of a string. ([Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html))
- `.` matches any character; In your case the first one. ([Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html))
- `i` here you match any `i` character.

So the regex looks for a pattern who has any character as the first one in the string followed immediately by the character `i`.

---

There is also a "short hand" version of this query since you don't actually need to specify the `$regex` operator if the value you pass is a regular expression.

```
db.col.find({ ename: /^.i/ });
```

Since the value to match against is not a string but rather a literal regular expression (it doesn't have quotes but rather slashes surrounding it), mongo will know to perform a regex match.

I prefer the first example since it is more explicit and leaves no "guess work" for future developers who come across your code.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.